# How to start filling items for the center in LazyVerticalGrid?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement a lazy grid in jetpack compose so that items are horizontally and vertically aligned, below is my code

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320, heightDp = 320)
    @Composable
    private fun ModuleGrid() {
        val modules = ModuleRegistry.getModulesList().toMutableList()
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().widthIn(120.dp),
                columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 96.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                
                items(modules,
                    key = { it.namedTag }
                ) {
                    Card(
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                            containerColor = Color.Transparent
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(120.dp)
                            .background(Color.Transparent)
                            .clickable {
                                launchModule(it)
                            }
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                        ) {
                            it.displayIcon?.let { icon ->
                                Image(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = icon),
                                    contentDescription = it.displayName,
                                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .size(96.dp)
                                        .padding(4.dp)
                                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                )
                            }
                            Text(text = it.displayName, modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output result is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEtGB.png)

This item should be displayed in the centre of the screen.

[image: Requirement]
[image: Requirement]

I tried using the horizontal grid but ended up getting a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use only one item per column remove items to be adaptive instead use `GridCells.Fixed` here is an example to make  LazyVerticalGrid items in the center of the screen:

```
    Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), // number of columns
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 100.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            items(20) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(120.dp)
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Item $it",
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above code aligns the items, only in the horizontal direction. For my use case, items must be populated from the centre of the screen.